# Why does list length reduce to sqrt(n) after each comparison in interpolation search?

Tags: algorithm, math, complexity-theory

According to the book I'm reading, interpolation search takes `O(loglogn)` in average case.
The book assumes that each compare reduce the length of the list from `n` to `sqrt(n)`. Well, it isn't difficult to work out the `O(loglogn)` given this assumption.
However, the book didn't talk more about this assumption except that it says this is correct.

Question: can anyone give some explanation on why this is true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the input being uniformly distributed (without such an assumption, O(log n) is the best you can do theoretically, ie binary search is optimal). With a uniform distribution, the variance is around sqrt(n), and in the expected case each iteration hits within the variance of the target. Thus, as you say, the search space goes from n -> sqrt(n) on each iteration.

Comment: I cannot folow your answer. What do you mean by "With a uniform distribution, the variance is around sqrt(n)"? The variance of a uniform distribution is (n^2-1)/12. Please clarify.

Comment: The standard deviation (I should have said) of the _guess_ of where to find the target is sqrt(n).

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a sorted array where each entry is a number from one to a million.  You want to look to see if 10000 is in the array.  As 10000 is less than 99% of the numbers less than one million, if the array has a nice distribution of numbers, chances are that an entry of 10000, if it is in the array, is very near the start.  If we look at an entry 1% percent of the way through the array, and find that it is greater than 10000, we have eliminated 99% of the array in a single step.  This is much better than a binary search, which only looks at the middle of an interval, and therefore can only eliminate at most half of the search space at a time.  This is intuitively why interpolation search in some cases can be much faster than binary search.

To see the rigorous analysis of why it is expected to be O(log log n) you would have to read through a textbook or paper on the algorithm.